# Using HttpClient async methods returns string wrongly formated

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I'm not sure if this error only occures when using ReadAsStringAsync() but i'm pretty sure that i hadn't have this problem with non async.

[image: WebAPI Result]

[image: Client Result]

The problem is that the returned string should be "10" and not "//"\"10\"" (JSON formated)

How can i fix this problem?
The serverside code is from the RESTful WebAPI and the clientside code is from the client which is communicating with the WebAPI.

**Edit #1:**
You guys probably missunderstood me.
i know that i get my string as i want it to be by using .Result() extension. 
But my question is how can i become the same result by using the awaitable function (without .Result()) ?

**Edit #2:**
Please comment the downvote. i don't understand what's the problem with my question? if it is a dumb question, then please tell me what i am not understanding

Comment: Show your code as a text, not as an image.

Comment: i can post the code as text.. but i used the screenshot to show you the result

Comment: @darkdog  What `content-type` did you request and what did you receive? Please post the code that creates the client request. The server obviously sends back the raw `"10"` in the body, probably formatted as JSON.

Comment: the content-type ist application/json @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: please comment the downvote

Comment: I'm pretty sure `async-await` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @PauloMorgado but that's what happening. without await -> response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result it's working .. but when i use await i can't add the .Result() extension. and i get the string like this: "//"\"10\""

Comment: If you use await, the call will be something like response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult() which will invariably call the same thing .Result calls. What .Result() are you talking about?

Comment: sorry i mean .Result (extension of async methods like ReadAsStringAsync().Result) .. i tried to use response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult(). it's neither awaitable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no issue here. The server returns the string value "10" to the client as the *raw* HTTP body of the response, with a content type of `application/json`. The value you see in `returnValue` is the raw value, before deserialization.

Once you deserialize the HTTP body you will get the original string.

The following console application snippet returns `"\"10\""' as the raw value but "10" as the deserialized value:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var s = client.GetStringAsync(@"http://localhost:7807/api/values/10").Result;
Debug.Assert(s=="\"10\"");

var s2=(string)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(s);
Debug.Assert(s2 == "10");
```

You can use `async\await` also, eg:

```
static async Task<string> GetDataAsync()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var s = await client.GetStringAsync(@"http://localhost:7807/api/values/10");
    var s2 = (string)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(s);
    return s2;
}
```

Comment: yes you are right. but how can i make it awaitable.. if i use .Result the return type isn't of type Task anymore..

Comment: Instead of `....Result` use `await client.GetStringAsync`. I used .Result because I created a console client.

Comment: oh i see. so i have to deserialize it by myself. that's a perfect answer :) thank you very much Panagiotis.